# How to prove that $\sum_{n_j\ge i-1}[n_j-(i-1)]-\sum_{n_j\ge i}(n_j-i)= \max\{j: n_j\ge i\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n_1\ge n_2\ge...\ge n_m$ so that $n_j\in \mathbb Z^{+}$  $\forall 1\le j \le m$ and let $i\in \mathbb Z^{+}$. Prove that:

$$\sum_{n_j\ge i-1}[n_j-(i-1)]-\sum_{n_j\ge i}(n_j-i)= \max\{j: n_j\ge i\}$$

What I did: Let $n_j-(i-1)=k$ then: $$\begin{align} \sum_{n_j\ge i-1}[n_j-(i-1)]-\sum_{n_j\ge i}(n_j-i) & = \sum_{k\ge 0}k-\sum_{k\ge 1}(k-1)\\ & = \sum_{k\ge 1}k-\sum_{k\ge 1}(k-1)\\ & = \sum_{k\ge 1}k-(k-1)\\ & = \sum_{k\ge 1}1 \\ & = \sum_{n_j\ge i}1 \end{align}$$

But I don´t know if this is correct; if so does that mean that $$\sum_{n_j\ge i}1=\max\{j: n_j\ge i \}?$$

I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is almost correct. It is just that $k$ depends on $j$ and so you cannot write
just $k$ because then it looks like you sum together first positive (nonnegative) integers.
But one can think as follows: if there exists $n_j$ such that $n_j=i-1$, then in the sum
$$ \sum_{n_j\geq i-1}[n_j-(i-1)] $$
the first term is zero, if there is no $n_j$ equal to $i-1$, then 
$$ \sum_{n_j\geq i-1}[n_j-(i-1)]=\sum_{n_j\geq i}[n_j-(i-1)]. $$
Hence, the LHS is actually
$$ \sum_{n_j\geq i}\bigl([n_j-(i-1)]-(n_j-i)\bigr)=\sum_{n_j\geq i}1. $$
Note that RHS in this last equality counts how many $n_j$ are greater or equal to $i$. 
Since $n_1\geq n_2\geq \cdots \geq n_m$ the number of those $n_j$ which are greater or equal to $i$ is precisely the maximal $j$ such that $n_j\geq i$.

Comment: thank you very much!! @Janko Bracic very clear answer :)